# How to make a HTTPS request via TOR?

Tags: java, ssl, https, tor, netlib

I use `SilverTunnel NG Netlib` Java-library for connecting to TOR from Java.

HTTP connection via TOR to port 80 and a direct HTTPS connection to port 443 connection works fine.
But, when I'm trying to establish a HTTPS connection via TOR to 443 port,
I get answer from server

> 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you can't get SilverTunnel to work, you could always use the proxy server that comes with the tor browser.

Comment: Cleaned up the needless code markup and put in proper quoting. Also you should not repeat tags in the question title.